# простейший XSS input

Tags: xss

Пусть имеется страница:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Tag FORM</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="submit" href="">
            <input name="o1" type="text" value="1" >
            </input>
        </input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

На ней я хочу выполнить вот это - `" ><script>alert(666)</script>`
Но дурацкая мозилла и ишак не поддаются на такое(не выводят алерт), в простейшем примере,  почему?

Comment: Как выполняете-то?

Comment: @andreymal 1) ввожу в инпут значение xss и энтер 2) ввожу xss и жму сабмит

Comment: Ну да, ничего не будет, потому что это ничего не делает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы пытаетесь вписать код в инпут и отправить форму не весть куда, не сделает простейший пример XSS.

Форма должна вести на обработчик или на саму страницу, где уже выведется ваша запись. В общем, сервер должен вернуть введенный вами код, если говорить просто.

Еще в вашем коде есть ошибки.

Comment: **В общем, сервер должен вернуть введенный вами код, если говорить просто**  Так редко происходит в реальных приложениях, зачем мне аргументы из контролов выводить на страницу, если я должен их обработать на сервере!?

Comment: Варианты могут самые разные, например, ситуация, когда пользователь неверно заполнит форму регистрации, допустим. Страница перезагрузится и выведет поля, которые пользователь заполнял с последней попытки отправки. В данном случае, если вы не отфильтруете значения, которые положите в value="" инпута, то получится этот элементарный xss.